# I want to convert an object to integertype in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to convert an object into an integer and pass it to a url but after making conversion it is converted into NAN.

```
export const fetchById= (id) =>dispatch =>{
    //id: object
    const d= id.toString(); //string
    const i= parseInt(d,10); //number
    console.log(typeof id); //number
    fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo?asteroid_id=${i}&api_key=demo_key`)
    .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data =>{
            // const d= {...data.near_earth_objects};
            return dispatch({
                type: actions.fetchByIds, data: data
            });
        });
```

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof i);` instead of typeof id

Comment: @komaljituri instead of editing the title of your question, [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that solved your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to converting whole object to string. since stringifying object will return result like `JSON.stringify()` and it would be like `"{key: val}"`

to implement current task you can directly parse variable to intenger, but make sure you want it as intenger and not float.

so your code would be likely to work if it would be written like so:

```
 export const fetchById= (id) =>dispatch =>{
     //id: object
     const i= parseInt(id); //number
     console.log(typeof id); //number
     fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo?asteroid_id=${i}&api_key=demo_key`)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data =>{
        // const d= {...data.near_earth_objects};
        return dispatch({
            type: actions.fetchByIds, data: data
        });
    });
```

by the way, there are no use of converting it to int because all you do is use it in query and query will be converted to string, if you log type of `asteroid_id` in server it will be string.

Comment: if i do it in this way then this error comes up: GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/?asteroid_id=2189058&api_key=rUMAsp8IhAlems93UacOKIslTV02425e5CbE8oub and the type of asteroid_id should be int.

Comment: 0:
code: 405
error_message: "Request method 'GET' not supported"
http_error: "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED"
request: "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/neo?asteroid_id=2021277"
__proto__: Object
for now it is showing this. but should contain {links, id, name etc}

Comment: no, not error object, object you are passing to fetchById

Comment: my mistake the "id" that im passing is  type string

Comment: then you would just need `id` instead of `id.id`